# Statistical Distance of a function of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

[This](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/032.pdf) cryptography .pdf has an introduction to statistical security in section 2.
Here, they define the statistical distance, and then make the claim that:

> For any function $f:\Omega\to\Omega'$, we have 
>   $$\Delta_{stat}(f(X),f(Y)) \leq \Delta_{stat}(X,Y)$$

It's then claimed that the proof is immediate from the definition of statistical distance, which they give as:

> $$\Delta_{stat}(X,Y) = \sup_{\substack{M\in \Omega \\ M\text{ measurable}}}|\mathbb{P}[X\in M] - \mathbb{P}[Y\in M]|$$

I don't see how this is immediate.
If $\Delta_{stat}$ is a metric (which it would make sense if it were), this seems like it's saying any function (not even continuous or measurable) is a contraction mapping.

Could someone help me figure this out?  If we assume $f$ is continuous, is this somehow true?

Comment: This is the famous *total variation distance*.  Note that any event of form $f(X)\in M]$ is already an event of form $[X\in M']$ for some other $M'.$

Comment: Ok, and $\Delta_{stat}(f(X),f(Y)) < \Delta_{stat}(X,Y)$ in cases where $f$ isn't injective?

Comment: I think that depends on what $X$ and $Y$ are doing.  Your guess is wrong, for instance, if $P(X=Y)=1.$